# Including/bundling dependencies in npm library with webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

I've used webpack for a few single page apps and am now trying to build an npm library to be used by some of those apps (and anyone else who might find it useful.)

I understand that peerDependencies in package.json and externals in the webpack config go together. If I'm writing an AngularJS plugin, I don't bundle angular, because the consumer should already have it installed and we want to work with whatever version they're using.

Where I'm confused is on how to include another library I don't expect the consumer to have. If I list it in dependencies and import it and don't include it in externals, webpack seems to bundle the other library with my code. I don't think this is what I want.

If I list it in dependencies and do include it in externals, it seems not to be available in the consumer unless I explicitly include it in the consumer, e.g. a script tag pointing to a CDN. It acts like a peerDependency, even though it isn't.

Is it possible to have have my library's dependencies installed by npm in the consumer app and available at runtime without a) bundling the dependency into my library or b) forcing consumers of the library to explicitly load an obscure package?